# PictureBox loses its image on navigating to different application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, picturebox

I started developing Windows Forms Applications recently. I'm working with PictureBox and I'm facing an issue with it. It is losing the image as shown in below pictures when I navigate out or if I minimize it and open it back. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Penguins.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                using (Image original = Image.FromStream(fs)) {
                    Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)original;
                    pictureBox1.Image = image1;
                    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    pictureBox1.Refresh();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException) {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the bitmap." +
                "Please check the path.");
        }
    }
```

[Forms Application before Navigating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNP5x.png)

[Forms Application after Navigating to another app or minimizing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XllkS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are disposing the image

```
using (Image original = ....
{
    Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)original;
    // ...
}
```

`image1` is the same object as `original`, just cast to `Bitmap`, and gets disposed right after being painted on the screen (with `Refresh` method).

To fix the problem, use the following instead

```
Bitmap image1 = new Bitmap(original);
// ...
```